# HTML não puxa CSS gerado pelo SASS

Tags: html, css3, express.js, sass, gulp

Estou usando express pra subir o server e gulp pra gerar o sass, o gulp gera corretamente o arquivo, porém, o css não é adotado pelo HTML. segue código :

Express :
    const express = require('express')
    const server = express()

```
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html')
});

server.get('/sobre', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/sobre.html')
});


server.listen(3003, () => {
    console.log('Servidor em pé em: localhost:3003')
})
```

Css

```
body{background-color:peru}
```

Meu HTML só tem isso :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/styles/styles.css">
    <title>Oi, eu sou o Goku</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oi, eu sou o Goku!</h1>
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/deathbattlefanon/images/2/20/C0A9B238-91F6-46AA-ABDC-3FC720228C25.png/revision/latest?cb=20171104014554" alt="Goku">
</body>
</html>
```

Não sei por que ele não adota o arquivo css, fiz testes e notei que, sem o express, ele pega o css normalmente, o que posso estar fazendo errado ? 
Chamando o express antes da pagina pegar o css ? Alguém já passou por isso ?

Erro do Console:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:3003/dist/styles/styles.css' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.

Estrutura de pastas 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o status no browser, da requisição http do style.css, não sei porquê

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador qual foi a resposta para a requisição HTTP do arquivo CSS? Eu diria que a pasta `dist` onde se encontra o seu CSS não está acessível via HTTP e por isso não consegue ser carregada.

Comment: Verifique sua estrutura de pasta assim como o Anderson falou. Se for possível cole ela aqui para que possamos ter um visão de como o projeto está sendo organizado, irá ajudar a ter uma resposta a princípio, caso a pasta ```dist``` esteja dentro da ```src``` o ```HTML``` não vai achar o arquivo ```CSS``` mesmo, pois está voltando uma pasta antes. Por isso a estrutura de pasta do projeto pode nos ajudar a responder.

Comment: Essa é a estrutura... No caso, ele encontra o css, se eu abro o arquivo html sem usar o express, o css funciona

Comment: Atualzei também com o erro que aparece no console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente:

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))


server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(dirname + '/src/index.html')
});

server.get('/sobre', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(dirname + '/src/sobre.html')
});


server.listen(3003, () => {
    console.log('Servidor em pé em: localhost:3003')
})
```

Adicionei a linha 3. Ela faz o express "enxergar" a pasta `dist`.

Depois você conseguirá acessar seu arquivo CSS assim: http://localhost:3003/styles/styles.css